# Read remote JS file as string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I'm trying to retrieve a remote JS file in NodeJS with http.get
although the file is accessible and readable in my browser, my http.get code is throwing:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
    at chunkInvalid (_stream_readable.js:372:10)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:124:12)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

I've tried multiple libraries but all came with the same error (probably most of them are just wrapping the http.get API)

I'm publishing my code although this is very basic.

```
    var request = http.get("http://nodejs.org/static/js/download.js", function(error, response,body) {
  console.log(body)
});
```

Using **Node 4.3.0** (5.6.0 didn't do any magic) on **Mac OS X 10.11.3**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is wrong, try like this:

```
var url = "http://nodejs.org/static/js/download.js";

var http = require('http');
http.get(url, function (res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.')
    });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('Got error: ' + e.message);
});
```

This code gives me:

```
301
BODY: <html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the http module is very basic and doesn't follow redirection, you should use something more powerful, [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for example:

```
var request = require('request');    
request.get(url, function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(res.body); // the output is the javascript code
});
```

Or the promisified version, [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise):

```
var request = require('request-promise');
request.get(url).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err.statusCode);
});
```